# Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm trying run this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Exemple 06</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Diretiva ng-repeat -->
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <a ng-href="#/">Page 1</a> | <a ng-href="#/p2">Page 2</a>
        <div ng-view="#/p2"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

        myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
            $routeProvider
                .when('/'  , {controller: 'MyController', templateUrl: 'p1.html'})
                .when('/p2', {controller: 'MyController', templateUrl: 'p2.html'})
                .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});
        });

        myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope){
            $scope.nomes = [
                {id: 1, nome: 'Arthur'},
                {id: 2, nome: 'Portos'},
                {id: 3, nome: 'Aramis'}
            ];
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

but the error below occur:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/93579551515/Desktop/Angular/p1.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

I don't want to run it on a webserver.

Comment: You can start a webserver locally as easily as `python -mSimpleHTTPServer` and then point your browser to `localhost:8000/index.html`.

Comment: out of curiosity .. why don't you want to run a webserver?

Comment: Run it in Brackets (http://brackets.io/), it will work.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can add templates such as `p1.html` and `p2.html` in your `index.html` by putting them inside `script` tags, as [mentioned in the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$templateCache).

```html
<script type="text/ng-template" id="p1.html">
  This is the content of the template
</script>
```

Then `angular` will no longer need to make AJAX requests to fetch them.

Do note that these `script` elements must appear *after* `ng-app`.

Comment: It would be cool if I could make a script to collect all my view files and inject them in such script tags in the bottom of the main page.
Does anyone know if such a script exists or how would I go about making it?

Comment: I receive this error when I use templates like this, the templates still function correctly, but it spams errors to the console.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same trouble in Chrome, if you are using Chrome, you can disable same origin policy in Chrome. Starting the Chrome runs:

```
$ google-chrome --disable-web-security
```

Here's [more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449716/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-but-its-not-cross-domain).

Answer (score 0):

Route provider uses http protocol that's why if you will run this code directly from folder, you will get cross origin issue.

Keep your folder on a server like **localhost/route** and run it.

Provide reference path like templateUrl: '/p1.html'