# Angularjs routing not working

Tags: angularjs, route-provider, ng-view

Everything worked fine until I tried to add routing. I read that Angularjs version 1.2+ requires 'ngRoute' as an dependency (I am using version 1.2.16). I added it but it still doesn't work. Below are my codes.

test.html (Main Page)

```
<html ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Front Page</p>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="testjs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

testjs.js

```
demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',['ngRoute']);

demoApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller: 'SimpleController',
        templateUrl: '/partials/first.html'
    });

});

var controllers = {};
controllers.SimpleController = function ($scope){
    $scope.first = "Info";
    $scope.customers=[
        {name:'jerry',city:'chicago'},
        {name:'tom',city:'houston'},
        {name:'enslo',city:'taipei'}
    ];
};
demoApp.controller(controllers);
```

first.html

```
<div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
    </br>
    {{first}}
    </br> 
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name">{{cust.name | uppercase}} - {{cust.city}}</li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

Comment: There is a link to a picture of my working directory: http://postimg.org/image/979tsaecd/

Comment: are you sure this is correct syntax: demoApp.controller(controllers) ?
I can't find any reference to it.

Comment: yes, I saw it in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uj-KLCTsQrw .

Comment: I will try to find the exact video time where I found the code. give me a second.

Comment: sorry it's actually in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAyEGv67P-U . And it is 10 minutes and 21 seconds into the video

Comment: and everything worked fine until I tried to do routing with .config

Comment: do you get any error in the console?

Comment: I didn't run it through the console. I simply opened with chrome. I just found out that I had the error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///partials/first.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP." when running on chrome. I am going to try to fix it. Thanks for now!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the most basic setup possble, I'll try to make another one with your code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/sN9TagVBOdX3mkrxaTiu?p=preview

**EDIT** updated with the sample code. Everything seems to be working?

**EDIT 2** the problem is OP wasn't running a webserver. Ng-Route needs a webserver to function properly.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to see what's wrong with my codes. Thank you though!

Comment: apparently I got this error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///partials/first.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP." I will try to fix it now. Thanks!

Comment: try using partials/first.html (without slash)

Comment: still the same result. I think I found the answer though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847252/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http . Really appreciated ur help.

Comment: that's not a really good answer. Is it possible you aren't running a webserver? That you are just viewing static html on your filesystem?
If so, then there is your problem. Ng-Route needs a webserver.

Comment: that's exactly the case. Everything works once I run it on a webserver

Comment: Another mystery solved :-) for local development you could use grunt to boot up a server :-)

Comment: I'v tried the same thing on tomcat server but its not working. some error showing like 1> Error: Unknown provider: $sceProvider <- $sce <- $route <- ngViewDirective and other one is 2> Circular dependency: ngViewDirective

Comment: that's a different question.

Answer (score 8):

My routing wasn't working because there was an exclamation point inserted in the url when I tried to navigate to my routes.  I added `$locationProvider` like this

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
```

to remove the exclamation point and my template views started appearing when I navigated to them.  I found the answer here [Exclamation mark after hash (#!) in angularjs app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41214312/exclamation-mark-after-hash-in-angularjs-app)