# angularjs route is changing my url

Tags: angularjs

I can't seem to get my route running...

If i go to: http://localhost:8000/#/notes, it changes my url to: http://localhost:8000/#!#%2Fnotes. This does not work either: http://localhost:8000/#!#notes.

Running angularjs 1.6 and route 1.6. I'm also using gulp webserver.

routes.js:

```
angular.module('NoteWrangler').config(function($routeProvider){

  $routeProvider.when('/notes', {
    templateUrl: '/templates/pages/notes/index.html'
  })

});
```

index.html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div ng-view>
   </div>
</div>
<script src="/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/angular/angular.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="routes.js"></script>
```

gulpFile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var webserver = require('gulp-webserver');

gulp.task('webserver', function() {
  gulp.src('./')
    .pipe(webserver({
      livereload: true,
      open: true
    }));
});
```

Comment: just a suggestion, please use ui-router.

Comment: I'm guessing your problem is the same as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211875/angularjs-1-6-0-latest-now-routes-not-working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs 1.6.0 (latest now) routes not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211875/angularjs-1-6-0-latest-now-routes-not-working)

Comment: and check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41214312/exclamation-mark-after-hash-in-angularjs-app for another solution

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it right but there is a change introduced in `angular 1.6.x` for `$locationProvider`. Prior to this version default value for `hashprefix` was empty '' but now it is '!'.

Check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider

and https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.11/docs/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider

Therefore modify your `route.js` as below

```js
angular.module('NoteWrangler').config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
  //$locationProvider.html5Mode(false); 
  //false is default therefore it is not required to set
  $routeProvider.when('/notes', {
    templateUrl: '/templates/pages/notes/index.html'
  })

});
```