# Angular Routes are not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

**app.js** I am trying to setup routes here but It is not working and I have no idea why its not working , kindly look into this issue.When I click on page1 the url should be /employees but it takes strange shape **http://localhost:3000/#!#employees**

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp',['ngRoute'])
myapp.config(function($routeProvider){
console.log('in the routes')
$routeProvider
    .when('/employees' ,{
        templateUrl: 'templates/index.html',
        controller: 'empController'
    })
    .when('/employees/create' ,{
        templateUrl: 'templates/create.html',
        controller: 'empController'
    })
    .when('/employees/:id/show' ,{
        templateUrl: 'templates/show.html',
        controller: 'empController'
    })
    .when('/employees/:id/edit' ,{
        templateUrl: 'templates/edit.html',
        controller: 'empController'
    })
})
```

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app='myapp' ng-controller='empController'>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/employees">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/employees/create">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/employees/:id/edit">Page 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/employees/:id/show">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<hr>

<div ng-view></div>
```

Comment: You can remove the ! in the url as shown in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41214312/exclamation-mark-after-hash-in-angularjs-app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL hash-bang (#!/) prefix instead of simple hash (#/) in Angular 1.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226122/url-hash-bang-prefix-instead-of-simple-hash-in-angular-1-6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your app. js like this in order to handle it.

```
.config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
    $routeProvider
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way,

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp',['ngRoute'])
myapp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
console.log('in the routes')
$routeProvider
    .when('/employees' ,{
        templateUrl: 'templates/index.html',
        controller: 'empController'
    })
    .when('/employees/create' ,{
        templateUrl: 'templates/create.html',
        controller: 'empController'
    })
    .when('/employees/:id/show' ,{
        templateUrl: 'templates/show.html',
        controller: 'empController'
    })
    .when('/employees/:id/edit' ,{
        templateUrl: 'templates/edit.html',
        controller: 'empController'
    })
})
```