# How to route angularjs

Tags: angularjs

my main directory folder name is **`angularjs`** and there have many files, file lists are given billow.

```
1.index.html
2.main.html
3.blue.html
4.red.html
5.green.html
```

i want to create routing using AngularJs, i have do that but facing error what i have wrong.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
      templateUrl: "index.html"
    })
    .when("/red", {
      templateUrl: "red.html"
    })
    .when("/green", {
      templateUrl: "green.html"
    })
    .when("/blue", {
      templateUrl: "blue.html"
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

  <p><a href="#/">Main</a></p>

  <a href="#/red">Red</a>
  <a href="#/green">Green</a>
  <a href="#/blue">Blue</a>
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

and i want to remove `#` simble from routing path

Comment: What is the error? and why are you using # in anchor links?

Comment: when i load this page my browser do not response

Comment: Have you tried without #? and browser do not response to what?

Comment: have tried that but nothing change

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-fragment-identifier-from-angularjs-urls-symbol

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your code with below.

```
<p><a href="#!">Main</a></p>

<a href="#!red">Red</a>
<a href="#!green">Green</a>
<a href="#!blue">Blue</a>

<div ng-view></div>
```

If you want to remove the exclamation mark, you should add a config to the `$locationProvider` as below.

```
.config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
    $routeProvider
```

Refer, 
[Exclamation mark after hash (#!) in angularjs app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41214312/exclamation-mark-after-hash-in-angularjs-app)