# angular js template problems

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm getting template load errors with angular and im following a guide. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as this is my first attempt at templating.

directory structure

```
index.html
app.js
home/home.view.html
home/home.controller.js
login/login.view.html
login/login.controller.js
register/register.view.html
register/register.controller.js
```

Here is the guide I'm using:

```
https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular-registration-login-example
```

the errors im getting:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/login/login.view.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.b @ angular.js:10661q @ angular.js:10480d.$get.g @ angular.js:10187(anonymous function) @ angular.js:14634a.$get.m.$eval @ angular.js:15878a.$get.m.$digest @ angular.js:15689a.$get.m.$apply @ angular.js:15986(anonymous function) @ angular.js:1658e @ angular.js:4473d @ angular.js:1656yc @ angular.js:1676Zd @ angular.js:1570(anonymous function) @ angular.js:28683n.Callbacks.j @ jquery.min.js:2n.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2n.extend.ready @ jquery.min.js:2I @ jquery.min.js:2
angular.js:12416Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///C:/login/login.view.html'.
    at Error (native)
    at b (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js:93:116)
    at q (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js:89:65)
    at d.$get.g (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js:86:221)
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js:118:217
    at m.a.$get.m.$eval (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js:132:358)
    at m.a.$get.m.$digest (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js:129:365)
    at m.a.$get.m.$apply (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js:133:113)
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js:19:479
    at Object.e [as invoke] (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js:39:96)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12416b.$get @ angular.js:9203(anonymous function) @ angular.js:14642a.$get.m.$eval @ angular.js:15878a.$get.m.$digest @ angular.js:15689a.$get.m.$apply @ angular.js:15986(anonymous function) @ angular.js:1658e @ angular.js:4473d @ angular.js:1656yc @ angular.js:1676Zd @ angular.js:1570(anonymous function) @ angular.js:28683n.Callbacks.j @ jquery.min.js:2n.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2n.extend.ready @ jquery.min.js:2I @ jquery.min.js:2
angular.js:12416Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$compile/tpload?p0=%2Flogin%2Flogin.view.html&p1=undefined&p2=undefined
    at Error (native)
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js:6:416
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js:143:420
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js:118:217
    at m.a.$get.m.$eval (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js:132:358)
    at m.a.$get.m.$digest (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js:129:365)
    at m.a.$get.m.$apply (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js:133:113)
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js:19:479
    at Object.e [as invoke] (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js:39:96)
    at d (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js:19:400)
```

app.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies'])
        .config(config)
        .run(run);

    config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
    function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller: 'HomeController',
                templateUrl: 'home/home.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })

            .when('/login', {
                controller: 'LoginController',
                templateUrl: 'login/login.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })

            .when('/register', {
                controller: 'RegisterController',
                templateUrl: 'register/register.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })

            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
    }

    run.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$location', '$cookieStore', '$http'];
    function run($rootScope, $location, $cookieStore, $http) {
        // keep user logged in after page refresh
        $rootScope.globals = $cookieStore.get('globals') || {};
        if ($rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata; // jshint ignore:line
        }

        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
            // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
            var restrictedPage = $.inArray($location.path(), ['/login', '/register']) === -1;
            var loggedIn = $rootScope.globals.currentUser;
            if (restrictedPage && !loggedIn) {
                $location.path('/login');
            }
        });
    }

})();
```

login.view.html

```
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h2>Login</h2>
                <div ng-show="vm.error" class="alert alert-danger">{{vm.error}}</div>
                <form name="form" ng-submit="vm.login()" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required }">
                        <label for="username">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.username" required />
                        <span ng-show="form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required" class="help-block">Username is required</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required }">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.password" required />
                        <span ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-actions">
                        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || vm.dataLoading" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                        <img ng-if="vm.dataLoading" src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
                        <a href="#/register" class="btn btn-link">Register</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </center>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-app="app"> 
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Classfied</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
            <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
            <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
            <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
<body>
       <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" >
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">San</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
              </ul>
              <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar" id='leftMenu'>
              <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Grants Room! <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">create room</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">join room</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">drop spoi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/register" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#register">register</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login">login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">add friends</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">public rooms</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">friends</a></li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <h4 style='color:#f9eefc;margin-left:10px;'>Grants Room Users</h4>
                <li><a href="#"><img src='static/img/user.png' style='width:35px;height:35px;margin-right:10px;align:left;'>grant zukel tracking: 
                <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">
                <img src='static/img/offline.png' style='width:26px;height:26px;margin-left:10px;align:left;'></a>
                </li>
              </ul>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main" id='heightMap'>
              <div class="row placeholders">
                <div id='chatWindow' class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 placeholder" style="background-color:#fdf4ff;">
                    <br>
                    <center>
                    <div ng-view></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 placeholder" >
                    <div  id="map" class='map' style="width:400px;height:850px;float:right;" ></div>    
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

<!-- Modal -->

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">spoi - "social point of intrest"</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="spoidesc">social point of interest description</label>
                <input type="text" id="spoidesc" class="form-control" id="spoidesc" placeholder="Description">
              </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="spoidesc">date </label>
                <input type="text" id="DD" class="form-control2" style="width:50px;" id="spoidesc" placeholder="DD">/
                <input type="text" id="MM" class="form-control2" style="width:50px;" id="spoidesc" placeholder="MM">/
                <input type="text" id="YY" class="form-control2" style="width:50px;" id="spoidesc" placeholder="YY">
                <label> time </label>
                <input type="text" id="HR" class="form-control2" style="width:50px;" id="spoidesc" placeholder="HR">:
                <input type="text" id="MIN" class="form-control2" style="width:60px;" id="spoidesc" placeholder="MIN"> 
                 <select id='daynight'>
                  <option value="AM">AM</option>
                  <option value="PM">PM</option>
                </select> 
            </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
                <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
                <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
                </label>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="dropMarker();" data-dismiss="modal" >Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


</body>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/chat.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.5/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.5/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>        
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>  

    <script>
        //set dynamic element height to help out with mobile layout
        $(document).ready(function() {
          function setHeight() {
            windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
            chatwindowWidth = $('#chatWindow').innerWidth();
            windowWidth = $(window).innerWidth();
            leftwindowWidth = $('#leftWindow').innerWidth();
            leftoverspace = windowWidth - leftwindowWidth;
            leftoverspace = leftoverspace / 2
            $('#chatBox').css('min-width', leftoverspace - 300);
            $('#chatinputbox').css('min-width', leftoverspace - 300);
            $('#map').css('min-width', leftoverspace-150);
            $('#inputChat').css('top', windowHeight-100);
            $('#map').css('min-height', windowHeight-50);
            //$('#map').css('min-height', windowHeight-50);

            $('#chatWindow').css('min-height', windowHeight-50);
          };
          setHeight();

          $(window).resize(function() {
            setHeight();
          });
        });
        //define map to use
        var map = L.map('map').setView([0,0], 13);
            L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoienVrZXJ1IiwiYSI6ImNpZWtzOXA4cjAwM2Jyd200eG1mNnVtZWsifQ.sOcXd9L2Nw2p-s0DOWvoRw', {
                maxZoom: 18,
                attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                    '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                    'Imagery � <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
                id: 'mapbox.streets'
            }).addTo(map);

        var popup = L.popup();
        var dropMarkerBool = "False";

        // check for Geolocation support
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          console.log('Geolocation is supported!');
          var options = {timeout:60000, enableHighAccuracy: true};
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation, errorHandler, options);
        }
        else {
          console.log('Geolocation is not supported for this Browser/OS version yet.');
        }

        //L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
        //  .bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a popup.").openPopup();

        //L.circle([51.508, -0.11], 500, {
        //  color: 'red',
        //  fillColor: '#f03',
        //  fillOpacity: 0.5
        //}).addTo(map).bindPopup("I am a circle.");

        //L.polygon([
        //  [51.509, -0.08],
        //  [51.503, -0.06],
        //  [51.51, -0.047]
        //]).addTo(map).bindPopup("I am a polygon.");

        function dropMarker(){
            dropMarkerBool = "True";
            return dropMarkerBool
        }
        function onMapClick(e) {
            if (dropMarkerBool == "False"){
                //do nothing for now
            }
            else{
                var name = $('#name').val();
                var spoidesc = $('#spoidesc').val();
                var dd = $('#DD').val();
                var mm = $('#MM').val();
                var yy = $('#YY').val();
                var hr = $('#HR').val();
                var min = $('#MIN').val();
                var ampm = $('#daynight').val();
                var spoi_html = "<div style='background-color:#492a52;color:#f8dbff;border-radius:15px;padding:15px;'>Name: " + name + 
                "<br>description: "+ spoidesc +
                "<br> date & time: " + dd+"/"+mm+"/"+yy+ " "+hr+":"+min+" "+ampm +
                "</div>";
                L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map).bindPopup(spoi_html).openPopup();
                dropMarkerBool = "False";
            }
        }
        map.on('click', onMapClick);


        function showLocation(position) {
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

            locationMarker = L.marker([latitude, longitude]).addTo(map).bindPopup("My Location").openPopup();
            L.circle([latitude, longitude], 500, {
                color: 'red',
                fillColor: '#f03',
                fillOpacity: 0.5
            }).addTo(map).bindPopup("acceptable error");
         }

         function errorHandler(err) {
            if(err.code == 1) {
               alert("Error: Access is denied!");
            }

            else if( err.code == 2) {
               alert("Error: Position is unavailable!");
            }
         }
    </script>   

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular-cookies.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="app-services/authentication.service.js"></script>
    <script src="app-services/flash.service.js"></script>

    <!-- Real user service that uses an api -->
    <!-- <script src="app-services/user.service.js"></script> -->
    <script src="app-services/user.service.local-storage.js"></script>

    <script src="home/home.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="login/login.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="register/register.controller.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should access your app through a web-server. The npm [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) is a simple alternative. This happens because any path-only URL are prefixed with the *default* host and schema for the original document. This is standard HTTP behavior, but you should not take my word for it. In your case this is file://, and CORS is not defined for file://.

look at this: [AngularJS routing without a web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677882/angularjs-routing-without-a-web-server)

You could try prefixing your templates with `./` as in `./template/foo/bar.htm`

Comment: ahh i see yea i didn't know that Im using a python api server for my calls so thats why im just running the index.html locally didn't know that thanks so much.